# List is being overwritten

Tags: python, selenium

So I am scraping listings off of Craigslist and my list of titles, prices, and dates are being overwritten every time the web driver goes to the next page. In the end, the only data in my .csv file and MongoDB collection are the listings on the last page.

I tried moving the instantiation of the lists but it still overwrites.

the function that extracts listing information from a page

```
    def extract_post_information(self):
    all_posts = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("result-row")

    dates = []
    titles = []
    prices = []

    for post in all_posts:
        title = post.text.split("$")

        if title[0] == '':
            title = title[1]
        else:
            title = title[0]

        title = title.split("\n")
        price = title[0]

        title = title[-1]
        title = title.split(" ")
        month = title[0]
        day = title[1]
        title = ' '.join(title[2:])
        date = month + " " + day

        if not price[:1].isdigit():
            price = "0"
        int(price)

        titles.append(title)
        prices.append(price)
        dates.append(date)

    return titles, prices, dates
```

The function that runs going to url and going to next page until there is no more next page

```
def load_craigslist_url(self):
    self.driver.get(self.url)
    while True:
        try:
            wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.delay)
            wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "searchform")))
            print("Page is loaded")
            self.extract_post_information()
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchform"]/div[3]/div[3]/span[2]/a[3]'))).click()
        except:
            print("Last page")
            break
```

My main

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
filepath = '/home/diego/git_workspace/PyScrape/data.csv'  # Filepath of written csv file
location = "philadelphia"  # Location Craigslist searches
postal_code = "19132"  # Postal code Craigslist uses as a base for 'MILES FROM ZIP'
max_price = "700"  # Max price Craigslist limits the items too
query = "graphics+card"  # Type of item you are looking for
radius = "400"  # Radius from postal code Craigslist limits the search to
# s = 0

scraper = CraigslistScraper(location, postal_code, max_price, query, radius)

scraper.load_craigslist_url()

titles, prices, dates = scraper.extract_post_information()

d = [titles, prices, dates]

export_data = zip_longest(*d, fillvalue='')
with open('data.csv', 'w', encoding="utf8", newline='') as my_file:
    wr = csv.writer(my_file)
    wr.writerow(("Titles", "Prices", "Dates"))
    wr.writerows(export_data)
    my_file.close()
    # scraper.kill()
scraper.upload_to_mongodb(filepath)
```

what I expect it to do is get all the info from one page, go to next page, get all of thats page info and append to the three lists titles, prices, and dates in the extract_post_information function. Once there are no more next pages, create a list out of those three lists called d (seen in my main function)

Should I put the extract_post_information function in the load_craigslist_url function? Or do I have to tweak where I instantiate the three lists in the extract_post _informtaion function?

Answer (score 1):

In the `load_craigslist_url()` function, you're calling `self.extract_post_information()` without saving the returned information.

Comment: That extract post function returns three lists. So when I call that function in load url should I  set it equal to a list and have load url return that list? Also should I instantiate the list before whole true to avoid it being cleared and re written?

Comment: Here I added a data list that instantiated on the first call of load URLs. I append the data from extract post information (i.e. three lists of titles, prices, and dates) to the data list. At of the method return the data list, Again it overwrites the contents from the first page while debugging and i need to keep the return statement itemsi in that same format of titles, prices, and date to pass to .csv

Comment: data = [] before while true and then data.append(extract post info) after the except statement on the same indentation of while true is return data